# Digital Counter not initializing to 0 or rolling over to 0

Tags: digital-logic, counter, troubleshooting, multisim

I'm trying to make a 3-bit counter using D flip flops that loops through the sequence (0,3,4,5,7) repeatedly.

So far, I've made a timing trace, block diagram, operation table, Karnaugh maps, rough circuit diagram, and implemented it in Multisim.

[image: Timing trace]
[image: Block diagram]
[image: Operation table]
[image: Karnaugh maps]
[image: Rough circuit schematic]

The sequence somewhat works. When I start the simulation from scratch, the 7 segment goes 3, 4, 5, 7, 5, 7... It does not initialize to 0 unless I press the reset button, in  which case it does the prior, but with a 0 before the 3. I cannot fathom why it decides to stick between the last two numbers of the sequence instead of rolling over to 0.

[image: Running the simulation]

Any tips on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Your timing trace shows states 0 0 3 4 5 2 7 which differs from what you specified (0,3,4,5,7)? If no one else answers I'll look at a solution later tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Karnaugh maps are correct (although not optimal since you haven't made use of the don't cares) but you're reading the sum-of-products off wrong.

Given that you are mapping 3 inputs, a product of only a single term must be a rectangle covering 4 cells.  Your rectangles cover only 2 cells, and therefore must be the product of two terms.

F0(Q0, Q1, Q2) = /Q0 /Q1 + /Q1 Q2

and

F2(Q0, Q1, Q2) = Q0 Q1 /Q2 + /Q1 Q2

If you fully minimize your k-maps,

F0(Q0, Q1, Q2) = /Q1

F1(Q0, Q1, Q2) = /Q1 /Q2 + Q0 /Q1 = /Q1 (Q0 + /Q2)

F2(Q0, Q1, Q2) = Q0 /Q2 + /Q1 Q2